# How to get Apache's mod_rewrite working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know it's been asked a hundred times, and I also took my time searching and trying. Somehow I still can't get it to work, only partially.

I have structure of urls like these: (xxxx can be numbers as well)

- `index.php?mode=xxxxx`
- `index.php?category=xxx`
- `index.php?product=xxxx`
- `index.php?article=xxxxx`
- `index.php?blog&post=xxxxx`

The url I'd like to see in the end of all variations:

- `www.example.com/something`
- `www.example.com/something/something` (in the blog&post case)

I also would like to hide index.php at the end.

Comment: We get so many "write this mod_rewrite rule plz" requests here, we really do need to see what you have tried. I have downvoted, as we _really_ don't write code for people who add deadlines to their posts. Time is short for everyone.

Comment: OK, to make it even more clear:

I would like to transform urls from
/index.php?article=xxxxx to /xxxxx
also
/index.php?product=xxxxx to /xxxxx

I have no idea how to make Apache know which parameter it should redirect to. It depends on the 'xxxxx' of course, every URL is unique.

I don't need the article/ or product/ or category/ etc. part of the URL, just the 'xxxxx' right after the domain.
An example:
'www.example.com/this-is-my-product'
instead of
'www.example.com/products/this-is-my-product'

I have done only research without success yet because I'm really caught by this.

Answer (score 0):

If only have numbers and nothing at the end, the rules would be:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mode/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?mode=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?product=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?article=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /blog&post=$1 [L]
```